# pendrive automount not working

Tags: ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive, mount, automount

There are lots of ways to disable pendrive automount. I used one, but regreted, forgot which one and now need to reenable pendrive automount. It may have been a changed setting after pressing a button while booting Ubuntu or a deleted folder named something20090101 or 01012009something or whatever as long as it's a word and a date... If I don't want pendrive viruses, it's disable autorun, but keep automount enabled, right? *blush*

UPDATE:

I reinstalled mount, installed autofs5 and run 'automount /dev/sdb1 /media/KINGSTON'.

It knows when I plug a pendrive in my computer (it adds a KINGSTON folder to Places -> Computer), but doesn't mount nor add a desktop icon.
It knows when I unplug a pendrive in my computer (it removes the KINGSTON folder from Places -> Computer), unmounts and removes the desktop icon.

Autounmounting is fine. Automount isn't.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `gparted` software to delete and reformat the drive, then restart the computer and it will work